# Passing parameters with express router correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/:category").get(getProductsByCategories);
router.route("/:id").get(getProductDetails);

export default router;
```

In this code, I've added two routes with parameters. But this code doesn't work as expected. The first route get products by categories works. But the second one doesn't. Could someone help me to troubleshoot this code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

From the Express documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

> Route parameters
>
> Route parameters are named URL segments that are used
> to capture the values specified at their position in the URL. The
> captured values are populated in the req.params object, with the name
> of the route parameter specified in the path as their respective keys.
>
> Route path: /users/:userId/books/:bookId
>
> Request URL: http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989
>
> req.params: { "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }

With that info, we can say your 2 routes are actually **the same**. The name of parameters doesn't make them 2 different routes. What it changes is only how the `req.params` object is populated. As the consequence, all the requests will go to the first route.

#### Suggestion

You will need to change 1 of 2 routes, for example :

- To get the product by ID, you can keep it :

```
router.route("/:id").get(getProductDetails);
```

- To get products by category, you can change to :

```
router.route("/category/:category").get(getProductsByCategories);
```

Answer (score 1):

your route actually same route

use query string

```
router.route("/").get(getProduct)
```

and in the product function

```
const {id,category} = req.query
```

don't forget to include the keyword in url request

```
{{url}}/product?id=1 // to get detail
{{url}}/product?category // to get product by category
```