# mutiple get methods on the same route conflict in express and sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm built simple product crud, so I have a route to search product by id and other to search product by name, when I make a requisition to http://localhost:4000/products?name=pen the routes are in conflict and don't return the product by name.

```
router.get('/products/:id', ProductController.getProductById);
router.get('/products/:name', ProductController.getProductByName);
```

and yours respect functions

```
const getProductById = async (req, res) =>{
    try{
        const { id } = req.params;
        const product = await Product.findByPk(id);
        if(product){
            return res.status(200).json({ product });
        }
        return res.status(404).send('Product With ID does exist');
    }catch (err){
        return res.status(500).send({ error : 'Error on select by id'})
    }
}

const getProductByName = async (req, res) =>{
    try{
        const name = req.query.name;
        const product = await Product.findAll({
            where: { name: name}
        });
        if(product){
            return res.status(200).json({ product });
        }
        return res.status(404).send('Product With Name does exist');
    }catch (err){
        return res.status(500).send({ error : 'Error on select by id'})
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149384/express-router-not-working-when-we-add-two-routes-with-parameters/67151833#67151833) answer your question ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use query parameters you should not indicate them in route path:

```
router.get('/products', ProductController.getProductByName);
```

Comment: I use /products to find all products, how to work with query parameters?. Ty for help

Comment: That's right. If you indicate `/products` without any query parameters you should get all products. If you indicate some query parameters that means you wish to filter all products by indicated criteria. That could be a part of a product name or maybe a price or something else.